# PLSQL- How to get the values of separate flow in a hierarchical flow of records

Tags: plsql, hierarchy, hierarchical-query

There is a set of records in a table which are in hierarchical order. I have to get the flows separately[image: heirarchichal flow]

As per the image, the separate flows will be like,

- A -> B-> D
- A -> B-> E
- A->C-> F
- A->C-> G

but the **number of levels are dynamic** and no. of **records per parent node can be also dynamic**
that means for example, **B** can have **D, E, H,O.. so on**

also these A,B,C... are not primary keys of this table

so this each record (A,B,C...) has **quantity** and **price** columns.

what I want to do is, calculate the **quantity*price** of each level with its previous level's quantity* price value in the separate flows. As per this example,

```
------------------------------
part  sub_part price quantity
-----------------------------
G     C        3       1
F     C        1       1
E     B        4       3
D     B        3       1
C     A        5       2
B     A        2       1
```

final results of each flow should be,

- A -> B-> D = 6
- A -> B-> E = 24
- A->C-> F = 10
- A->C-> G = 30

no. of flows is not stable. this depends on the no. of records in hierarchy, which is dynamic

I tried with hierarchical queries but I cannot do the calculation in the same query.
also tried saving the records in arrays but since they are dynamic, that didn't give expected results.

Comment: Provide some data in proper sql format with table and expected result which would prompt anyone to try for a solution fast.

Comment: Normally we can perform a hierarchical query using [connect by](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Queries.html#GUID-0118DF1D-B9A9-41EB-8556-C6E7D6A5A84E) or recursive WITH clause, without any need for PL/SQL.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 I have added the table and expected results. can you give me a solution

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Can you please elaborate with a simple example

Comment: From your sample "final results" is seems that the hierarchy always starts with A. However, there is no part A.

Comment: yes.it is always from a sub_part the connection starts from. because that is the only value provided and has to find the rest of the flow depending on the sub_part